# App don't work under IE 9

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I deployed my app successfully on GAE (Java), and the thing works as expected under Chrome (and others) under MacOS X. Today at work I wanted to test my app on IE 9.0.8 / Vista, and the app won't load.
My app displays a "loading" message on the page until all objects of the UI are loaded. When I load the UI I also fetch some data using RPC. When the job gets done the loading message disapears and my app shows up.
As I don't see any error or Exception / nothing special in the app engine logs, how can I start to find the bug ?
The only difference I see is that, at work, my computer goes online trough many firewall and proxys, but as i can open the page and login it should not be a problem. But anyway, just after I login (using google accounts, not openID) the app "hangs". Ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You should start by [inspecting network connections in IE9](http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-faster-with-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-9/#fbid=3BUv1RR4dAp?one) to see if everything loads as expected. See also [GWT tricks for IE9](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideIE9).

Comment: Good tip, thanks. But the Dev Tools are not available to me. Blocked by a network policy... Any Idea for some tool that would do the same ? My computer at work is totally secured, I cannot install anything..

Answer (score 1):

Try running your GWT app in dev mode, this way you should be able to see the client-side errors in the GWT console. Client-side error messages are not displayed in Web mode, unless you implemented code to handle them.